# How to most effectively store the values ​of the matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I calculate some matrix in my program. It is large in size about 5000x3000. I would like to make calculations once, save them, and later load the matrix values ​​from the file, fill it. What is the best way to implement it and in what ways?

Comment: NumPy arrays are the goto choice for matrix calculations. Further, NumPy has `numpy.save()` and `numpy.load()` functions which can store/load numpy arrays, using `.npy` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the best thing for you is to use the [numpy library](https://www.numpy.org/). It's the fastest in terms of matrix calculations for Python.

For storing the matrix for later use you can either use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to have it serialized in binary or just write it to a [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in plain text. You can also use the numpy [save function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) to store the matrix for later use, which is probably also as fast.